# Adding space to select option in form alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I have taxonomy terms hierarchy and I am using them as a filter in a view. It is showing hierarchy in the selectbox, but child terms appearing with hyphen(-). I have tried to drop hyphen in form alter, and I did, but I couldn't replace it blank space.

```
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($form['field_region_tid']["#options"] as $op) {
            foreach ($op->option as $key => $arr) {
                if ($arr != null) {
                    $form['field_region_tid']["#options"][$i]->option[$key] = str_replace("-","&nbsp;", $arr);

                }

            }
            $i++;
        }

    }
```

**How can I put blank space at the beginning of the child options.** Or should I do some other way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the form_id I get that it is a form generated by views. If so, the code inside the `if` condition never gets called because your module is executed after the views module due to the weight of both modules. To fix that:

1. Open your database manager (PhpMyAdmin in most cases) and open `system` table.
2. Then change the weight for your module to something larger than 10, because it is the default weight for the views module and you need you module to be executed after the views module.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Muhammad "if" condition gets called, but option are showing &nbsp; as a string not blink space.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is when your hook is called the answer lies in

```
hook_module_implements_alter()
```

but it is not as you say. Your code looks fine,
Have you tried

```
str_replace("-"," ", $arr);
```

?